# How to meet eslint max line length rules with long svg path?

Tags: eslint

The eslint max line length is set to 120, but I have a svg and its path is longer than 120, what can I do to meet the max-line-length?

```
<path d="M47.2388, 12.45 ...................."/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"max-len": ["error", {"ignoreTemplateLiterals": true, "ignoreStrings": true}]
```

or

[ESLint-plugin-React](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react)

Comment: ignoreTemplateLiterals does not aply in here and ignoreStrings depending on the framework (like VUE) it is possible not working.

Answer (score 26):

The accepted answer is wrong, the "d" attribute of a path is not a Template Literal so ignoreTemplateLiterals does not make sense.

In the same way, ignoreStrings does not work, at least in my vue project.

The best solution for me is to use **ignorePattern** like this:

```
ignorePattern: 'd="([\\s\\S]*?)"'
```

You alway can check the documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, but this worked for me - thanks! +1

Comment: it worked for me, formatted like so: `"ignorePattern": "d=\"([\\s\\S]*?)\""`

Answer (score 1):

In case you're working with VueJs, I had to add the following code inside rules to ignore max-len for SVG urls in scoped css.

```
'max-len': ['off', {
  code: 100,
  ignoreUrls: true,
}],
```